# NestJS: Mongoose timestamp properties in generated OpenAPI spec

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger, nestjs-mongoose

I'm using `@Schema({ timestamps: true })` to add `createdAt` & `updatedAt` to my records and returning these with the response. But seems the OpenAPI spec getting generated by the NestJs's Swagger plugin is not adding the `createdAt` or `updatedAt`. How can I get these two added to the generated OpenAPI spec.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
paths:
  /participants/{participantId}:
    get:
      operationId: ParticipantController_findOne
      parameters:
        - name: participantId
          required: true
          in: path
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The participant
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Participant'
components:
  schemas:
    Participant:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        description:
          type: string
        participantId:
          type: string
      required:
        - name
        - description
        - participantId
```

My controller looks like this

```js
@ApiOkResponse({
  description: 'Get a participant',
  type: Participant,
})
@Get(':participantId')
findOne(
  @Param('participantId') participantId: string,
): Promise <Participant> {
  return this.participantService.findOne(participantId);
}
```

My Mongoose schema looks like this,

```js
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Participant {
  @Prop()
  @ApiProperty()
  participantId: string;

  @Prop()
  @ApiProperty()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  @ApiProperty()
  description: string;
}
export const ParticipantSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Participant);
```

My response looks like this,

```json
{
    "name": "Participant One",
    "description": "The particicpant one",
    "participantId": "participant-001",
    "createdAt": "2022-10-14T20:00:52.778Z", // Added automatically by the `timestamps: true`
    "updatedAt": "2022-10-14T20:04:31.081Z",// Added automatically by the `timestamps: true`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add createdAt and updatedAt to schema without @Prop()

```
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Participant {
  @Prop()
  @ApiProperty()
  participantId: string;

  @Prop()
  @ApiProperty()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  @ApiProperty()
  description: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  createdAt: Date;

  @ApiProperty()
  updatedAt: Date;
}
export const ParticipantSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Participant);
```